# SELinux dpkg postinst script permission denied

Tags: debian, selinux, dpkg, debian-stretch

selinux installed on debian 9 (stretch)

when i try to install something (tried w/ different packages) w/ dpkg (or apt) it fails with the following error message:

```
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/cmatrix.postinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package cmatrix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

i am root, and the issue occurs even in **permissive mode** (it works when selinux is disabled)

dpkg has the label 'dpkg_exec_t'. the postinst file's permissions are the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:dpkg_var_lib_t:s0 192 May  4 16:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/cmatrix.postinst
```

i can run the script directly from the terminal w/o errors.

i tried to install the sid version of selinux, but the error occured there too.

the installed policy is the default policy.